# Perl Regex to match a string that is not enclosed in quotes

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write regex to match a string that is NOT inside quotes (double or single), but the best I can do so far is a loop to iterate through all characters of a string. There must be a simpler, more elegant solution.

Examples: If trying to replace `foo` with `bar` the string `hello foo!` would become `hello bar!`, but the string `you said "my name is foo"` would stay the same.

Could anyone help out with a regexp to achieve the above?

Comment: I think we'd need to see more examples.  Most importantly: Is that your entire string?  Or is that a sub-string of a larger document?  Show two or three examples of inputs, and their associated expected results and I can write (and explain) a regex for you, or suggest a tool with less overhead.

Comment: I am assuming you are not worried about "double quote levels" - in other words, that `Hello "brother" foo, how are "you" doing?` is considered to have `foo` in quotes (although syntactically it doesn't). Can you confirm?

Answer (score 3):

One way, using a negative lookahead:

```
perl -lane 's/foo(?![^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/bar/g; print' input
```

which means substitute if the number of quotes ahead is not odd. So this one assumes you have balanced quotes in the input.

*Example input:*

```
hello foo!
"foo" foo "foo"
foo "hello" foo
"foo" bar
```

*Example output:*

```
hello bar!
"foo" bar "foo"
bar "hello" bar
"foo" bar
```

Comment: Fails on `"foo" bar`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed by adding an additional char class

Comment: Not fixed. Try `"foo" foo "foo" bar`

Comment: Right, moved that negated class to the end of the lookahead

Comment: I keep almost commenting on this but always end up not, lol.  It's tough to fight the creativity of this regex.  It almost flawlessly works around balancing **after** foo.  Unfortunately, Perl regex support for lookbehinds isn't as forgiving.  Also, this doesn't work for *proper* single-quotes, which isn't really a concern if you add Apostrophes to the muddy water here.  So I up-voted because I like your creativity.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Quick-Summary:** While you'd need "Balancing Groups" to really handle this, the short answer is, you can't do it if you require Single-Quotes too.  Because those double as Apostrophes.  So no matter what, this would really screw you up: `That's when foo said, "That's my line!"` balancing gets very thrown out of whack with apostrophes.  You'll need to build a custom parsing engine.

**Note:** If this is for HTML Properties... I have written a Regex that properly parses them exactly as you say, and I believe would work in Perl.  But that also relies on delimiters like the `=` sign and other HTML Structures.  But in 90% of those cases, an XML/HTML Parser is the best option (That 10% is still a possibility).

As I mentioned in my comment to your question, more examples would give more concrete answers. This is the answer for your limited example:

```
^([^"']*?)foo([^"']*)$
```

Lookarounds are easy for an intermediate regex writer, but complicated for code maintainance and usually not what was needed.  Also, anything that requires you to use a Dot `.` in regex is typically not as efficient as it could be.

Replace my example with `$1bar$2` and you'll be golden.  But again, as my comment says, this is based on your basic example which assumes your entire string is that which may start with and end with quotes.  If you have different examples they would help.

### *Addition*

Just for fun, I'm going to answer your question for two other options.  Option 1 is my original answer above.

**Option 2** (As mentioned by Floris):

```
Hi foo, I said "hello"
```

Or

```
"hello", said foo to his friend.
```

If this is the case, where quoted text will only appear BEFORE or AFTER your search-text (foo in this case), then the answer is like so:

```
^(?:([^"']*?)foo(.*)|(.*?)foo([^"']*))$
```

**Option 3** (as seen in my comment below)

```
He said, "Hello", so then Foo told him, "Lawl, bye"
```

To do this, we'd have to count the number of Quotes before and after foo, to be sure they are either even, or that they "close out" known as "Balancing" in .NET Regex, neither of which options are available in your circumstance without some other custom functions.

Comment: Even with the limited description given, I'm pretty sure that there could be quoted text before or after `foo`, in which case I think your expression would not work. `Hi foo, I said "hello"`, with your expression, would not find a match for `foo`.

Comment: That's correct.  But if that's the case, he'll need to say so.  And he'll also need to say if this is an option: `He said, "Hello", so then Foo told him, "Lawl, bye"`.  If that's the case, he'll need a different tool, because only .NET Regex can handle "nesting" checks to see whether he is inside or outside of the quotes.  So without him specifying more information, my answer is so far as correct as can be given in terms of regex I believe.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by an *intermediate regex writer*. Do you mean between an expert and a novice skill wise?

Comment: Correct.  An intermediate regex writer could throw lookarounds all over the place because they know how they work, but that doesn't mean they're correct, or most efficient, or that they are maintainable by other developers in the future who don't know lookarounds.  And in this instance, they are unnecessary.

Comment: @hwnd Right. You used the first regex, which I said would be used as a literal answer to the limited information in the question. Then my second option matches for replacing using `$1bar$2`, which is this: [Option 2](http://www.regex101.com/r/tB4wM9).  Which, as it says, works only when there is quoted data in one direction from an un-quoted `foo`.  And I also note that if there **is** data on both sides, you'll get into regex that is not used correctly unless you use balancing of .NET, which isn't an option here.  As you said in another comment, another tool may be better if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to do this as well, so solved it myself...  This solution does not rely on balanced quotes, but obviously will not support apostrophes if they come in pairs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @test = ( 'hello foo!',
             '"my name is foo"',
             'foo test "test foo test" test foo test "test foo test" test foo',
             "foo test 'test foo test' test foo test 'test foo test' test foo",
             '"foo test foo"',
             'foo test " foo test' );

foreach ( @test )
{
  s!("[^"]*"|'[^']*')|foo!$1//'bar'!ge;
  print "$_\n";
}
```