# regexp ignore match inside double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace the space with some special character in phrase. But I am matching the space on conditions only. check below examples for understanding!

I don't want to match the space with trailing and leading special strings like

> AND, OR, NOT, -

My example string

```
apple google AND bing NOT yahoo
```

In above example I want to match only space between  **apple google**. So write below code.

```
$q = 'apple google AND bing NOT yahoo';
$pattern1 = '/(?<!AND|NOT|OR)[ ](?!-|AND|NOT|OR)/';
$replacement1 = ' ## ';
echo $qs = preg_replace($pattern1, $replacement1, $q,-1);
```

Here is the output

> apple ## google AND bing NOT yahoo

My problem Now, string with quotes. I want ignore the space between quotes.

> "apple google" AND bing NOT yahoo    => should be 0 match

So how to write the expression to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl-regex-to-match-a-string-that-is-not-enclosed-in-quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193876/perl-regex-to-match-a-string-that-is-not-enclosed-in-quotes)

Comment: what should `"apple google" linux` return?

Comment: @Robin: It should ``"apple google" ## linux``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
$s = '"apple google" AND bing NOT yahoo "word a-b"';
$r = preg_replace('/(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?<!AND|NOT|OR) +(?!-|AND|NOT|OR)/i', 
                  ' ## ', $s);
echo "$r"; // "apple google" AND bing NOT yahoo ## "word a-b"
```

This assumes that quotes are balanced in the input as it detects text inside quotes by counting even # of quotes following in lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
(?<!AND|NOT|OR")[ ](?!-|AND|NOT|OR|[a-zA-Z]+")
```

**Edit**

I had another think and this should work:

```
(?<!AND|NOT|OR)[ ](?!-|AND|NOT|OR|(([a-zA-Z])\s?)+[a-zA-Z]")
```

**Edit 2**
For words with Hyphens in

```
    (?<!AND|NOT|OR)[ ](?!-|AND|NOT|OR|(([a-zA-Z-])\s?)+[a-zA-Z]")
```

**Edit 3**

See anubhava's answer for a nicer approach :)

Comment: That's great! but if I add three words inside the quotes I am getting ``"apple ## google engine" AND bing NOT yahoo``

Comment: Hmm. I cant think of a definitive answer to this. Look behinds cannot be zero width and it is hard to say where one quote ends and begins.

Comment: Won't work if input is `"apple google" AND bing NOT yahoo "word a-b"`

Comment: @Martyn: Actually there are so many other ways this approach will break.

Comment: For example: `'"apple google" AND bing NOT yahoo "word a b"'`